# rendering a list of varying length in html page

Tags: javascript, html, loops

hi
I need to render a list of objects(eg. hotels) in html page and the user should select a hotel then the hotel id should be posted back to the controller,
the length of that list is not fixed let it be n, so i thought of creating n radio boxes but i realized that html doesn't support loops, and i don't know if it is possible to create forms within javascripts

note
I'm using play framework in that application

any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML doesn't support loops because it isn't a programming language. It doesn't allow conditional statements, functions, value assignment, etc. It is merely for specifying content. I think it would benefit you greatly to brush up on the basics of web development so you have a clear grasp of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and the server side languages of your choice. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the Play framework, so I can't offer any assistance with that. I can tell you that this is a very easy task in every framework I have ever used.

Comment: Apparently Play is a framework for Java/Scala. In that case, in your view code you'll want to iterate over the list of hotels and emit an input tag for each one.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the basic concept of how to iterate over an object and print out html. Not perfect, not exactly what you need, but a starting point.

```
var hotels = ['best western','hilton','super 8'];
for( var i=0; i<hotels.length; i++ )
{
    document.write( '<input type="radio" name="hotels" id="' + i + '" />' + hotels[i] );
} // for
```

[In action](http://jsfiddle.net/v6a7q/)

Comment: thanks but would this work if the list of holtels is passed from the controller to the view not a variable defined within the script ??

Comment: I'm not sure how your particular framework works, but you could probably set a variable to the output from the view.. Like, in Django or something `var hotels = ${hotels};` But this is probably over complicated. I'm sure there's a way you could just print a list from your controller?